# How to install previous version of vee-validate?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vee-validate

I am building a project on Vue and Laravel. I have bought a templates based on Vue and it is not supported newer version of Vee-validate so I have to install vee-validate2.*

I tried few instructions online but no one seems to be stating clearly.

Please help I am using Yarn to install plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list versions available:

```
yarn info vee-validate versions
```

To install one of the available versions:

```
yarn add vee-validate@3.0.8
```

Answer (score 4):

You can install particular version using `@version` like as below and you can check available version [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate) and install or using command as :

```
npm info vee-validate versions // to check versions
npm install vee-validate@2.0.0 // to install
```

OR

```
yarn info vee-validate versions // to check versions
yarn add vee-validate@2.0.0 // to install
```

If you want in  `dependencies` module then add flag after above command `--save`

Comment: As of npm 5.0.0, installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed.